# difference between org.hibernate.Session and org.hibernate.classic.Session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session

I am writing a DAO class. Here, I wanted to create a Session, while importing I saw two possible imports. i.e org.hibernate.Session and org.hibernate.classic.Session. I wanted to know the difference between them. What are the advantages to use either of them.

I have found out that org.hibernate.Session object is used to store the session returned from the 
`sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();`
However I would like to know about org.hibernate.classic.Session

```
org.hibernate.classic.Session session = 
                      sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); // compilation error
org.hibernate.Session session2 = 
                      sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

I expect to know the differences.
Any answer is welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use should use org.hibernate.Session.

org.hibernate.classic.Session is extended from org.hibernate.Session and includes only deprecated methods. This interface is created for easy migration of existing applications.

Check further information in the documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/classic/Session.html).